# Testing React App - Firebase Emulators / Mock Service Worker

Tags: reactjs, firebase, msw

I have recently started using Mock Service worker as a method to intercept my HTTP requests for my testing suite. I would like to do something similar in a project with Firebase, and am wondering if it is possible to use the emulators instead of Mock Service Worker?

As of right now, I think the only way to write integration tests using Firebase is to mock the library in the mocks folder and return the values you expect. Has anyone had experience with using the Emulators in the same manner as Mock Service worker?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully complete this using [Cypress-Firebase](https://github.com/prescottprue/cypress-firebase)

Comment: does cypress-firebase allow you to mock the authenticated user, or does it just provide an easy way to actually authenticate against the live server?